# Visual Studio not picking up references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I created a new class library, accepting the default settings, and added a couple of packages via nuget (Sendgrid, System.Data.SqlClient below).

[image]

There's also a project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ClassLibrary1 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "adamwhitehouse" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "Sendgrid": "8.0.3"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
}
```

When I try and reference these in the generated `Class1.cs` file, it's as if they don't exist, although they appear to be referenced exactly as the others (System.Collections, System.Threading, etc).

[image]

I've done absolutely nothing besides what I've outlined here. I'm sure it's something stupid, but I haven't created a project in Visual Studio in a while and it seems things have changed. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Visual studio and what king of project it is ? windows class library, core,... ?

Comment: it's all in the question, vs 2015 class library project

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduced that kind of project structure either in windows class library neitehr in core class library. Your references are in beta, I don't see how to do that

Comment: Ah.. I think I used the wrong project type, hold on

Comment: I can't seem to find an official announcement, but didn't Visual Studio drop support for the project.json project file and call it a failed experiment? I create a new project in VS2015 with all the latest updates, and I get the old traditional csproj file.

Comment: Core class library still have project.json for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, my new project dialog defaulted to Class Library (Package), which is apparently not what I wanted.

When I went back and selected the correct project type, everything works as expected.

[image]

Comment: That's why I was asking precisions fot the project type ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reason for this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: @Wendy Yes, what good is the internet if we can't learn from each others stupid mistakes :) I can't accept my own answer for another day, but will when I'm able

Answer (score 0):

try running `Update-Package -reinstall` in the nuget console, I fixed a similar issue by adding the -reinstall part